# borel set on a closed domain

Tags: measure-theory

For any $\Omega$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ we use the notation
$\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ for the set of Borel sets in $\Omega$. 
Fix an open domain $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Do we have 
$\mathcal{B}(D) = \mathcal{B}(\bar{D})$?
Here $\bar{D}$ is the closure of $D$.

Comment: closure of an open set is closed, so it's Borel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $\Omega=(0,2)\cup(2,4)$, and call $A=(1,3)$. Then clearly $A \subset \overline{\Omega} =[0,4]$, thus $A \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\Omega})$ but even $A \not\subset \Omega$, thus $A \notin \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2):

Not in general, for $D\ne \mathbf{R}^d,\varnothing$. This is because $D=\overline{D}$ implies that $D$ is open and closed, meaning it must either be $\mathbf{R}^d$ or $\varnothing$, from $\mathbf{R}^d$ connected.

With the above assumption, we have $D\subsetneq \overline{D}$ and therefore $\overline{D}\notin \mathcal{B}(D)$ while $\overline{D}\in\mathcal{B}(\overline{D})$. This is because $\overline{D}$ is closed, i.e. Borel. So, $\mathcal{B}(D)\subsetneq\mathcal{B}(\overline{D}).$

Comment: That's accounted for by assuming that $D\ne \mathbf{R}^d$. The only other case is the degenerate case where $D=\varnothing$, but I don't believe that is considered an open domain.

Comment: No, you are completely correct. I'm just pointing out that I state $D\ne \mathbf{R}^d$.

Comment: I think that my post is poorly written, pedagogically speaking. I will edit some, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

We do have
$$
\mathcal{B}(D) = \{ D \cap B \;:\; B \in \mathcal{B}(\bar{D})\} .
$$